# LACP for higher throughput?

Tags: fedora, switch, 10gbit, lacp

Given a D-Link DGS-1510-20 switch, which features 2x 10Gbps SFP+ ports and 20 1Gbps RJ45 ports and a Fedora-based server with 4x 1Gbps RJ45 ports, is there any configuration setting that allows me to attain 4Gbps throughput for a single stream when the copper is connected only to the Fedora server and the remaining devices are connected via 10Gbps copper links to another switch, which is connected to the D-Link switch via 10Gbps fiber?

I have so far tried bonding and teaming and have set up a link aggregation channel in the D-Link switch but still get only gigabit performance with iperf3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Link aggregation allows for an *aggregated bandwidth* of the ports' sum but *not for any single stream*. You'll need a faster port on the server for that.

The reason is that LACP or static LAG always forward traffic between two hosts or services using the exact same port pair. Depending on the devices and their configuration, traffic distribution may be seleced by source/destination MAC addresses, source/destination IP addresses, or source/destination IP addresses and transport-layer ports.

On the DGS-1510 series, you can select the traffic distribution using `port-channel load-balance {dst-ip | dst-mac | src-dst-ip | src-dst-mac | src-ip | src-mac}`.

The reason for this kind of traffic distribution is to guarantee that packets do not arrive out of order because that would causes severe performance penalties far worse than port congestion.

Comment: Thank you. I am getting another 10 GbE NIC.